# parsing data using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am learning BS4, and I am trying to scrape several tables, lists, etc. from popular sites to familiarize myself with th syntax. I am having a hard time getting a list in the right format. This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests

headers = {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
}

url = 'https://www.yahoo.com'

req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
terms = soup.find('ol').get_text()
print terms
```

Which prints the following list:

```
1Amanda Knox2Meagan Good3Dog the Bounty Hunter4Adrienne Bailon5Powerball winner6Gillian Anderson7Catherine Zeta-Jones8Mickey Rourke9Halle Berry10Lake Tahoe hotels
```

The right terms are separated by numbers, which adds an additional level of work, to parse the file so it reads kike "Amanda Knox", "Megan Good", etc.

Since I am not very familiar with BS4, is there a way to get the terms after the "tile=" tag inside my definition of terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because there are multiple elements inside the `ol` tag and `get_text()` joins the text of every tag out there.

Instead, you can use a [`CSS Selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to get the actual terms:

```
for li in soup.select('ol.trendingnow_trend-list > li > a'):
    print li.get_text()
```

Prints:

```
Hope Solo
Christy Mack
Dog the Bounty Hunter
Adrienne Bailon
Powerball winner
Catherine Zeta-Jones
Mickey Rourke
Valerie Velardi
Halle Berry
Lake Tahoe hotels
```

The `ol.trendingnow_trend-list > li > a` css selector matches every `a` tag that is directly inside `li` that is right inside the `ol` tag with `trendingnow_trend-list` class attribute.

FYI, this is to get the list of `Trending Now` terms from the block on the top right.